Use Metal Texture in RealityKit
I have an incoming handler that is providing MTLTextures quite fast, and I want to map those textures to a RealityKit material. I've been trying to figure this out with no luck. I tried converting each texture to a CGImage but that doesn't seem good for performance and it crashes. There's a texture drawable api but little documention. Any ideas?
var material: SimpleMaterial = .init()
private var textureResource: TextureResource!

func onMetalTexture(mtlTexture: CVMetalTexture) {
        
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: mtlTexture)
        let ciContext = CIContext()
        if let cgImg = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
            
            if textureResource == nil {
                textureResource = try! .generate(from: cgImg, options: .init(semantic: .color))
                
                let texture = MaterialParameters.Texture.init(textureResource!)

                material.color = .init(tint: .white, texture: texture)
            } else {
                try! textureResource.replace(withImage: cgImg, options: .init(semantic: .color)) // this crashes
            }
        }
    }

My RealityKit models are referencing 'material'.
